# JPA/Hibernate - Object does not save to the database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

```
@Service
@Transactional
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HTMLParser {

    public static final String link1;
    public static final String link2;
    public final String url;

    private final @NonNull VillageRepository;
    

    public void parseLink(String link, String selektor){

        // 1. úroven - získej z hlavního odkazu všechny obce nutné k proklikání
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();

            Elements links = doc.select(selektor);

            for (Element alink : links) {
                System.out.println("text: " + alink.text());
                parseLink(vytvořURL(alink.attr("href")), "div.sloupec3 a");
            }

           
            if(links.isEmpty()){

                links = doc.select("dl.sloupec dd");
                Village village = extractInformation(links);

                obecRepository.saveAndFlush(obec);

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        

public void parseLink(String link, String selektor){
        
                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
     
                    Elements links = doc.select(selektor);
                    
                    for (Element alink : links) {
                        parseLink(createURL(alink.attr("href")), "div.sloupec3 a");
                    }
        
                    if(links.isEmpty()){
        
                        links = doc.select("h4.navigace a");
                        Set<String> hiearchie =  extractHiearchy(links);
                        Iterator<String> iterator = hiearchie.iterator();
        
                        links = doc.select("dl.sloupec dd");
                        Village village = extractInfo(links);
        
                        villageRepository.saveAndFlush(village );
        
                    }
        
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    
    
        private Village extractInfo(Elements elements){
                if(elements.size() != 13){
                    elements.add(3, new Element("<dd><span class=\"sede\">--- ---</span></dd>"));
                }
                Village village = new Village(Long.parseLong(elements.get(7).text()), elements.get(0).text(), elements.get(1).text(),
                        elements.get(2).text(), elements.get(3).text(), elements.get(5).text(), elements.get(6).text(),
                        elements.get(8).text(), getHours(elements.last()));
        
                village.setEmails(extrahjZBloku(elements.get(9)));
                village.setWWW(extrahjZBloku(elements.get(10)));
                village.setPhones(extrahujTelefony(elements.get(11)));
                village.setAccounts(extrahujÚčetAIBAN(elements.get(4)));
            
                return village;
            }
    
    
        @Entity
        @Getter
        @Setter
        public class Village {
        
            public Village (){}
        
            @Id
            private long code;
        
            @Column
            private String type;
        
            @Column(name = "name")
            private String name;
        
            @Column
            private String adress;
        
            @Column(name = "sec_adress")
            private String secAdress;
        
            @Column(name = "bank")
            private String bank1;
        
            @Column(name = "bankovní_spojení2")
            private String bank2;
        
            @Column
            private String IBAN1;
        
            @Column
            private String IBAN2;
        
            @Column
            private String IC;
        
            @Column
            private String DIC;
        
            @Column
            private String shortcut;
        
            @Column
            private String email1;
        
            @Column
            private String email2;
        
            @Column
            private String email3;
        
            @Column
            private String email4;
        
            @Column
            private String www1;
        
            @Column
            private String www2;
        
            @Column
            private String www3;
        
            @Column
            private String www4;
        
            @Column
            private String telefon1;
        
            @Column
            private String telefon2;
        
            @Column
            private String telefon3;
        
            @Column
            private String telefon4;
        
            @Lob
            @Column(name = "hours")
            private String hours;
        
        
            }
    
    public interface VillageRepository extends JpaRepository<Village, Long> {
    }
```

My problem is that object village in the method parseLink does not save to the database... nothing happens and not even error shows up... When I try to save that object in the main method with with test parameters, it works, but not where I need... When I try to save something different in that method, nothing also happens, so the problem must be in the method parseHTML i guess
Thanks for help

PS: In intelij, i can see created insert command which seems to OK, but nothing is in the database...

Comment: add some logger and check if it goes inside the if loop and also add @transactional annotation to you method

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `@Transactional` annotation on the public functions, instead of the class.

Comment: did not help :/

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you really distributed into classes, but is it your JpaRepository decorated with the annotation @Repository ??